# web scraping with python and extract the HTML data and format it into a data excel

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, web, junit-jupiter

I am currently working on a web scraping project using Python, and I'm facing a challenge when it comes to extracting HTML data and formatting it for Excel. Here are the key details:

1. I have successfully scraped a website using Python.
2. Now, I want to extract the HTML data and format it into a structured form that can be easily read in Excel(i want it a data not a html to use it in my project).

I've tried using BeautifulSoup for HTML parsing and Pandas for creating a DataFrame, but I'm unsure about the best approach to format the data for Excel.

Could you please provide guidance or code examples on how to convert the scraped HTML data into a format suitable for Excel? Any advice on libraries or techniques for this specific task would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
web = 'https://www.flashscore.com/match/Y79ZlOP1/#/match- 
summary/match-summary'
response = requests.get(web)
content = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as it in seeking more in recommendations then in direct programming issue.s - Please take the [tour], read [ask], provide the code you have written and get stuck as [mcve], so that everybody could reproduce your issue. Thanks